# Mathematica FindMinimum redundant evaluations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The following code evaluates the objective function at the same point more than once as evidenced by the output of the Print function. Why does Mathematica perform these redundant steps? Seems inefficient.

```
obj[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ, z_?NumberQ] := Module[{},
  Print[x, "   ", y, "    ", z];
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2]
minisub = 
 FindMinimum[obj[x, y, z], {{x, 1}, {y, 2}, {z, 3}},  Method -> "Newton"]
```

Comment: Using the following `Print` statement shows that the same point isn't evaluated as much as your code might suggest. `Print[SetPrecision[x, 20], "   ", SetPrecision[y, 20], "    ", 
 SetPrecision[z, 20]]`

Comment: Using memorization reduces the `AbsoluteTiming` by a factor 1.4 on my machine.